# Pullback of a Weil divisor?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

How to define the pullback of a Weil divisor $D=\sum n_iY_i$? I'm particulary interested in $T^*_xD$ where $x\in X$, $X$ is an abelian variety and $T_x: X\rightarrow X$, $z\mapsto z+x$ is the translation morphism. Do we have that $Supp (T^*_xD)=SuppD-x$?

Where $SuppD-x$ is obtained by $SuppD$ after translating the points by $x$.

I hope this is true because I'm trying to understand the proof of the Theorem at page 163 from [Mumford, Abelian Varieties](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~pavel/cmi/References/Mumford_Abelian_Varities.pdf), and if $Supp (T^*_xD)=SuppD-x$ then I understand the proof (or at least that part).

Thanks!

Comment: I believe that for the pullback, the support is contained in the preimage of the function, so in your case it does just mean $Supp(D)-x$ as you think.

Comment: Your $T_x$ is an automorphism (of the variety, not the group structure), no? So I don't think there's any issue with defining what it means to pull back.

Comment: The title and the question in the first sentence are more or less orthogonal from the actual situation you are asking about. In general one cannot pull back Weil divisors. But you are in an extremely special case where (a) you are pulling back by an automorphism, and (b) your variety is smooth, so everything is a Cartier divisor anyway.

Comment: Let me be more explicit: if $D$ is a prime divisor on a variety on $X$ and $f$ an automorphism of $X$ then $f^*D$ had better be the prime divisor $f^{-1}(D)$. Now extend by linearity. I hope the question about the supports is clearly a "yes" now. There are general mechanisms for pulling back Cartier divisors (see Mumford's _Curves on an Algebraic Surface_) and pushing/pulling Weil divisors under certain more restrictive conditions (see Fulton's _Intersection Theory_) but you do not need this here.